# Unable to Upgrade Prometheus Blackbox Exporter to v0.24.0 via Helm using chart v8.10.1 on AWS Kubernetes - Error: resource mapping not found for name

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, kubernetes-helm, amazon-eks, prometheus-blackbox-exporter

I'm trying to upgrade Prometheus Blackbox Exporter to v0.24.0 using Helm chart v8.10.1 on my AWS EKS Kubernetes cluster v1.25 but it is failing with the following error:

```
helm upgrade -n monitoring prometheus-blackbox-exporter prometheus-community/prometheus-blackbox-exporter --version 8.10.1
Error: UPGRADE FAILED: unable to build kubernetes objects from current release manifest: resource mapping not found for name: "prometheus-blackbox-exporter" namespace: "monitoring" from "": no matches for kind "PodSecurityPolicy" in version "policy/v1beta1"
```

How to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Solution:

First, you need install `helm-mapkubeapis` (one time action per AWS EKS Kubernetes cluster). Then you need to run `helm mapkubeapis` for the `prometheus-blackbox-exporter` Helm release and then you need to delete the `prometheus-blackbox-exporter` Helm release and then you need to install it again.

Below you can see all the commands for the above mentioned steps:

```
helm plugin install https://github.com/helm/helm-mapkubeapis
helm mapkubeapis -n monitoring prometheus-blackbox-exporter
helm del -n monitoring prometheus-blackbox-exporter
helm install -n monitoring prometheus-blackbox-exporter prometheus-community/prometheus-blackbox-exporter --version 8.10.1
```

*Note: It is assumed that the Prometheus Helm charts repository is already added to your AWS EKS Kubernetes cluster. If not, you can run the following command to do so: `helm repo add prometheus-community https://prometheus-community.github.io/helm-charts`*